# Simplify multiple if fields validations in swift

Tags: swift, validation, if-statement, uitextfield

i'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to handle this sign up validation, especially the last section where there're three if blocks. For completeness i've to say that **every alert has a different message to show**.

```
func fieldsAreValid() -> Bool {
  guard let email = (view.viewWithTag(1) as? UITextField)?.text,
    let password = (view.viewWithTag(2) as? UITextField)?.text else {
      //  show an alert
      return false
  }

  if !email.isEmail {
    // show an alert
    return false
  }

  if !password.isAStrongPassword {
    // show an alert
    return false
  }

  if isASignUp() {
    if let verification = (view.viewWithTag(3) as? UITextField)?.text {
      if verification != password {
        // show an alert
        return false
      }
    } else {
      // show an alert
      return false
    }
  }

  return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion:

```
func fieldsAreValid() -> Bool {
    let emailField = view.viewWithTag(0) as! UITextField
    let passwordField = view.viewWithTag(1) as! UITextField
    let verificationField = view.viewWithTag(2) as? UITextField

    guard let email = emailField.text,
        let password = passwordField.text else {
            return false
    }

    let isEmail = email.isEmail
    let isStrongPassword = password.isAStrongPassword
    let isLoginOrValidSignup  = !isASignup() || verificationField?.text == password
    return isEmail && isStrongPassword && isLoginOrValidSignup
}

func validateForm() -> Bool {
    let valid = fieldsAreValid()
    if !valid {
        // show alert
    }
    return valid
}
```

I think it's better to use `as!` to cast the views to `UITextField`s because this is something that should always work. If say, the view with tag 0 is not a `UITextField` you probably want to find out during development and therefore it's okay to crash right there.

Comment: Actually i've forgot to mention that the verificationField is something optionally hideable. So if i'm trying to login the field is going to return nil causing the code to crash.

Comment: Ok, I modified the code. Now verificationField is an optional. I also had to change `verificationField.text == password` to `verificationField?.text == password`.

Comment: Ok, i see the point but what about user feedbacking? In your solution i'd not be able to show an alert.

Comment: Ah ok. I updated my answer again with a wrapper function that takes care of the alert.

Comment: Sorry if i'm always disappointing you but your solution would work only if i'd like to display a generic alert like 'Data not valid'. What about email is not well formatted? I'm start to thinking that maybe my solution is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Swift got a great feature I love to use for this case:

guard statement

here a very good explanation : http://ericcerney.com/swift-guard-statement/

In your case I would write :

```
func fieldsAreValid() -> Bool {
    guard let email = (view.viewWithTag(0) as? UITextField)?.text,
        let password = (view.viewWithTag(1) as? UITextField)?.text else {
          //  show an alert
          return false
      }

guard email.isEmail else {
    // show an alert
    return false
}


guard password.isAStrongPassword else {
    // show an alert
    return false
}


if isASignUp() {
    guard let verification = (view.viewWithTag(2) as? UITextField)?.text else {
        // show an alert
        return false
    }

guard verification == password else {
    // show an alert
    return false
}

//here your code if isASignUp is true

}

//here your code if it's a login ;)

return true

}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good practice, actually a guard it's meant to be placed as the first or at last the second instruction of the block. [link](http://ericcerney.com/swift-guard-statement/)